# NSArray issue in segmentedcontrol

Tags: nsarray

I used [this example](http://redartisan.com/2010/5/26/uisegmented-control-view-switching) to create a segmented view. In my `viewDidLoad` method I am getting a warning and code crashes.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.segmentedViewControllers = [self segmentedViewControllerContent];

    NSArray * segmentTitles = [self.segmentedViewControllers arrayByPerformingSelector:@selector(title)];

    self.segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:segmentTitles];
    self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    self.segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;

    [self.segmentedControl addTarget:self
                              action:@selector(didChangeSegmentControl:)
                    forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = self.segmentedControl;
    [self.segmentedControl release];

    [self didChangeSegmentControl:self.segmentedControl]; 
}
```

I am getting a warning in this line:

```
NSArray * segmentTitles = [self.segmentedViewControllers arrayByPerformingSelector:@selector(title)];
```

that `NSArray may not respond to arrayByPerformingSelector.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arrayByPerformingSelector:` is not a valid message to be sent to `NSArray`. This method is probably in one of the category extensions of `NSArray` that the original code uses. Check the original example you are following and try to find where `arrayByPerformingSelector:` is defined, then `#import` that file in your code.

Answer (score 0):

`arrayByPerformingSelector:` is a connivence method someone has written to avoid doing this:

```
NSMutableArray * tempArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for (id thing in things)
{
     [tempArray addObject:thing.name];
}
NSArray * namesOfthings = [tempArray copy];
```

However, there is already something in the iOS stack that will do this for free!

```
NSArray * namesOfthings = [things valueForKeyPath:@"unionOfObjects.name"];
```

You can read more about [KVC collection operations in NSHipsters blog post](http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/).  For an obscure API it's actually really useful.  I am sad it took me this long to find it.