# how to resolve the issue: "'Instance method '-arrayByPerformingSelector:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')"

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsarray, xcode4.2

i saw in one post `-(id)arrayByPerformingSelector` declaration in interface should do , but when i tried it this declaration was treated as separate method and incomplete implementation issue came... sorry this is quite a silly doubt i am asking but I'm a newbie to iOS and wasn't able to find out whats wrong with this..

```
self.segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[viewControllers arrayByPerformingSelector:@selector(title)]];
self.segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
```

and also when i run the project thread stops with SIGABRT and in console window

```
"TableView[866:fe03] -[__NSArrayI arrayByPerformingSelector:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e65620
2012-03-07 12:31:16.074 TableView[866:fe03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI arrayByPerformingSelector:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e65620'"
```

if i have to use selector in declaration please do tell me how.... Thanks all :):)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8385135/988769

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the iOS SDK and couldn't find a method with that name.  Considering it is making the app crash... there isn't a method with that name.

If you get that same type of warning and your app works fine, my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538884/im-getting-a-warning-using-objectfromjsondata) would be relevant

I don't know if you got started on this SO question: [Implementing my own navigation controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222369/implementing-my-own-navigation-controller), but the accepted answer there references a blog.

Researching that, you will need to:
• download *NSArray+PerformSelector.h* and *NSArray+PerformSelector.m* from [here](https://github.com/crafterm/SegmentedControlRevisited/tree/master/Classes)
• add them to your xcode project
• add `#import "NSArray+PerformSelector.h"` to the .m file you are experiencing your crash in.